# What does 'Extra arguments at positions in call' mean?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a string - "productRaw" which I am splitting up to show in separate `sectionData` cells, whilst under the same "Item 1" `cellData` table view. This is the code I am using to split up the String and add each separate part to a separate `sectionData` cell.

```
let group_array = document["product"] as? [String] ?? [""]
                                 
let productName1 = group_array.first ?? "No data to display :("
                                 
let productRaw = "\(productName1)"

let componentsRaw = productRaw.components(separatedBy: ", ")
                                 
var product = [String: String]()

for component in componentsRaw {
      
       let keyVal = component.components(separatedBy: ": ")

       product[keyVal[0]] = keyVal[1]
                                 
       }
                                 
       if let productName = product["Product Name"], let listingPrice = product["Listing Price"], let briefDescription = product["A brief description"], let productURL = product["Product URL"], let activeUntil = product["Listing active until"] { 
                                 
       self.tableViewData = [cellData(opened: false, title: "Item 1", sectionData: [productName],  [listingPrice], [briefDescription], [productURL], [activeUntil])]
 }
```

Where I am declaring the individual cells I want to be shown for the first section - "Item 1", when I only use `[productName]` in my `sectionData` then this compiles without any issues. However when I also add `, [listingPrice], [briefDescription], [productURL], [activeUntil]` to my `sectionData` I receive the following error for the `[cellData(opened:` syntax.

> Extra arguments at positions #4, #5, #6, #7 in call

So my question is, why am I receiving the above error and what can I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I only use [productName] in my sectionData then this compiles

`[productName]` is an array with one item in it.

> I also add , [listingPrice], [briefDescription], [productURL], [activeUntil] to my sectionData

You're adding extra arrays, separated by commas, which the compiler is interpreting as extra function arguments.

```
self.tableViewData = [cellData(opened: false, title: "Item 1", sectionData: [productName, listingPrice, briefDescription, productURL, activeUntil])]
```

Put all of the items inside a single set of square brackets. That's how you declare an array with multiple items.

Comment: Perfect - thank you. I'm still learning Swift so this information has been very helpful to know!

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to know what's wrong without seeing the declaration of `cellData`, however as far as I know the most obvious reason would be, that the constructor of `cellData` only takes 3 argument instead of 7.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795035/swift-extra-argument-in-call) they also mention, that this error could be thrown if you don't pass along the correct type for each argument.

We could help more if given the definition of `cellData`

Comment: I have managed to resolve my issue by using @jrturton's support, I was adding each of my items as separate array items, which caused the compiler to interpret these as extra function arguments.